# one xslt to rule them all

Tags: xslt

So here is my problem...

I have 2 xsl transformations and they both have xsl:for-each in them as a starting point.

I need to create one (master) xslt which will call them. But of course, there is a catch.

This new xslt should give output one node from first xslt, then one node from second.(both xslt have EmployeeId, but are basically different reports that have to be printed one after another).

Because these existing xslt's have for-each in them, when I include them in this master xslt I get an output: all nodes from first xslt, then all nodes from second.

Also this 2 xslt's have to be backward compatible, so they should work as before if they are not called from this master template.

I'm a starter to xslt and I managed to create some reports when working with only one xslt,but I can't seem to find the solution to this problem, so I appreciate all the help I can get.

I was thinking of creating a new xslt that would be a mix of two that I have, but this was ruled out by my boss.

Thanks,
Benxy

EDIT:

Here goes some examples as requested:

This is the first xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="windows-1250" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/" name="testXslt1">
    <xsl:for-each select="a">   
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@SomeData"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
                etc.            
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="b" mode="tmp"/> 
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="tmp">
    <tr >
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@SomeOtherData"></xsl:value-of></td>
        etc.
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Second xslt is similar to first one.

In Master xslt I would import both of them and in for each call templates testXslt1 and testXslt2.

Comment: You need more clarity in your language. I suspect that you are using "xslt" as a synonym for xsl:template - it is not. XSLT is a language. There are XSLT files and it's possible to read your post as referring to two separate xslt files, though I don't think so. Can you give a simple chunk of code (no more than 20 lines) to give an idea of the problem - prose is not a good way of explaining

Comment: @Benxy: Without stylesheet, I can only give you general answers. You have two functions to map like in `t1 list = map f1 list` and `t2 list = map f2 list`. So you have to use `t3 list = zip (t1 list) (t2 list)` or `t3 list = map f3 list` where `f3 item = (f1 item) : (f2 item)` or `f3 item = map (\x - x item) [f1:f2]`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete code example of doing the wanted mixing of the results of two independent templates. :)

Comment: @Benxy, please support the community by marking accepted answers on your past questions.

Comment: -1 @Benxy unless you reply to requests for clarification and also accept answers people will stop trying to help you. Your question has several possible meanings - I am not surprised your boss will not accept your solutions as s/he is unlikely to understand what you are trying to do. It's selfish to expect the community to help you unless you put in some effort

Comment: +1 @Benxy Thanks for clarification. It is now clear that there are TWO *.xsl files and that you are using the xsl:import mechanism. Maybe @Dimitre will be able to amend his answer to allow for xsl:import. It is possible that it may be useful to use xsl:param to control the process.

Comment: @zzzzBov - You are right, my bad, should have done that, no excuses.
@peter - I don't understand my boss why don't we do a new xslt. This way I have to edit 2 old xslt's which are how knows how old and how wrote them. And create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This new xslt should give output one
>   node from first xslt, then one node
>   from second

**Here is a simple example how this can be done**:

**This transformation** combines the results of two templates that are applied on the XML document.

The first templates produces twice the value of every `/*/*` node. The second transformation produces the square of the value of every `/*/*` node. The results of applying the two remplates each on the XML document are mixed together in alternation as required, and this is the final result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfResults1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/"
         mode="transform1"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfResults2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/"
         mode="transform2"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vResults1"
   select="ext:node-set($vrtfResults1)/node()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vResults2"
   select="ext:node-set($vrtfResults2)/node()"/>

   <xsl:for-each select="$vResults1">
     <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

     <xsl:copy-of select=".|$vResults2[$vPos]"/>
   </xsl:for-each>

   <xsl:if test=
     "count($vResults2) > count($vResults2)">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "$vResults2[position()>count($vResults1)]"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/" mode="transform1">
   <xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select=".+."/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/" mode="transform2">
   <xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select=".*."/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<num>2</num>
<num>1</num>
<num>4</num>
<num>4</num>
<num>6</num>
<num>9</num>
<num>8</num>
<num>16</num>
<num>10</num>
<num>25</num>
<num>12</num>
<num>36</num>
<num>14</num>
<num>49</num>
<num>16</num>
<num>64</num>
<num>18</num>
<num>81</num>
<num>20</num>
<num>100</num>
```